# ¿Por que mis media queries no funcionan?

Tags: css, css3, responsive, mediaqueries

He tenido algunos problemas con mis Media Queries.

He intentado de todo pero parece que no son reconocidas y no generan ningun cambio a la hora de cambiar el ancho de la ventana, la verdad no se si alguien me podria decir que estoy haciendo mal, aqui añado el HTML y el CSS para que se pueda ver.

Solo puedo decir que algo que he podido notar es que parece que solo e primer media querie que pongo es el que afecta el diseño sin embargo los otros parecen ser ignorados.

> Inicio de CSS

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Sora', sans-serif;
}


#grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
}

/*NAV PRINCIPAL*/

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}

#nav_principal {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#nav_principal li {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


#contacto {
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
}

/*COLORES*/

.azul {
    background: rgb(36,11,235);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(36,11,235,1) 9%, rgba(22,37,199,1) 44%, rgba(11,45,229,1) 68%);
}

/*LANDING PAGE*/

#landing_portada {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background: url("https://graphberry-imgs.imgix.net/isometric-technology-illustration-231.jpg?auto=compress,format&q=80&w=800") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.giant-title {
    color: white;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 25px;
}

#descripcion_landing {
    width: 60%;
    text-align: justify;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 25px;

}

#llamada_accion {
    padding: 25px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}


/*MEDIA QUERIES*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    #landing_portada {
        height: 110vh;
    }

    #description-landing {
        font-size: 1.7em;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
};

@media only screen and (max-width: 601px){
    #landing_portada {
        height: 10vh;
    }

    #description-landing {
        font-size: 1.6em;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
};

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    #nav_principal {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 25px 0;
    }

    #contacto {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
    }

    #landing_portada {
        height: 120vh;
    }

    .giant-title {
        width: 70%;
    }

    #descripcion_landing {
        width: 80%;
    }
};
```

> Inicio de HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XCalculadora-Calculadora del Futuro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
</head>
<body>
    
     //codigo

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sora:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</body>
</html>
```

Cualquier informacion que pueda aportar se las dare...

Comment: Necesitamos el HTML y tus reglas css para comprobar lo que ocurre

Comment: Hola @Joel, falta que agregues código HTML y reglas CSS para completar tu respuesta, ya que nos permitiría visualizar dónde está el problema que estás presentando. Sin embargo, te adelanto dos cosas: 1) Para que te funcione, al menos, en un Smartphone o Tablet, debes utilizar la etiqueta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`; 2) La última _Media Queries_ está sobrescribiendo la primera.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, ya lo añadi. Si he insertado el viewport pero parece seguir igual.

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero creo que si inicias #landing_portada con un height por ejemplo, luego en el mediaquery deberías añadir !important para que se tenga en cuenta. Otra opción es no iniciar con height y ponerles los height solo en los mediaquery, con el resto de opciones igual.

Answer (score 1):

Quita los `;` al final de las media queries, no se necesitan, y estan bloqueando las definiciones

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    #landing_portada {
        height: 110vh;
    }

    #description-landing {
        font-size: 1.7em;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 601px){
    #landing_portada {
        height: 10vh;
    }

    #description-landing {
        font-size: 1.6em;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    #nav_principal {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 25px 0;
    }

    #contacto {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
    }

    #landing_portada {
        height: 120vh;
    }

    .giant-title {
        width: 70%;
    }

    #descripcion_landing {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

Ademas fijate en el orden de las declaraciones, para evitar que se sobrepongan de manera inesperada. Las declaraciones posteriores sobreescriben a las anteriores. Por ejemplo una pantalla >= 801px

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px){} /* 1, sobreescrito por 3 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 601px){} /* 2, descartado */
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px){} /* 3, sobreescrbe a 1 */
```

En una pantalla > 550px

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px){} /* 1, descartado */
@media only screen and (max-width: 601px){} /* 2 sobreescrito por 3 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px){} /* 3 sobreescribe a 2 */
```

Por lo que cualquier definicion repetida sera sobreescrita (min-width: 801px siempre sera sobreescrita en tu caso). El orden de precedencia siguiente seria menos obstructivo:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px){} /* 1 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 801px){} /* 2, sobreescribe a 1 solo si es mayor a 800px */
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo, mas o menos, el mismo problema. Pero en mi caso cuando declaro el min-widht, este mismo no se resalta en el vs code, es como si fuera que no lo reconoce y se queda simplemente tipeado en color gris. Lo solucione yendo a developer Mozilla y copié directamente la sintaxis del media queries de ahí y en ese caso si me reconoció el min-widht. Dejo esta respuesta por si a alguien le pasa igual pues que sepan que de esa manera se soluciona, al menos eventualmente. No se a que se deberá ese error ya que el Vs Code no me detecta ningún error de sintaxis ni nada.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/310470)